Setting the type of second parameter based on the value of the first parameter
So basically if i call test with one of isText or isNumber strings it will decide what type to accept.
type EvtType = 'isText' | 'isNumber';
function test(firstParam: EvtType , secondParameter: /*firstParam ===isText ? string : number*/)
{
  //...
}

test('isText',2)// error
test('isText', "hey")// works


You can use a rest parameter whose type is a union of tuples as shown in this playground link. Does that meet your needs? If so I could write an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Yea that seem to work, explain pleaee

There are various approaches. Generally speaking a function's parameter types arew static and don't depend on anything.  If you want a function's parameter types to depend on each other, you either have to use either generics, overloads, or destructured rest parameters, depending on your use case. They all behave reasonably well from the caller's side, but the implementer of test() might find some approaches better than others.
Generics
You can make test generic in the type K of the firstParam, and write secondParameter as a condtional type that mimics your pseudocode:
function test<K extends EvtType>(
    firstParam: K,
    secondParameter: K extends "isText" ? string : number
) {
    //...
}

test('isText', 2)// error
test('isText', "hey")// works

Another generic approach which the compiler has a better chance of "understanding" in certain use cases than conditional types is to make a helper interface and look up the type in that interface:
interface ParamMap {
    isText: string,
    isNumber: number
}
function test<K extends keyof ParamMap>(
    firstParam: K, secondParameter: ParamMap[K]
) {
    //...
}

test('isText', 2)// error
test('isText', "hey")// works

Overloads
The traditional way to do this sort of thing is overloads, where you just write separate call signatures followed by the implementation:
function test(firstParam: "isText", secondParameter: string): void;
function test(firstParam: "isNumber", secondParameter: number): void;
function test(firstParam: "isText" | "isNumber", secondParameter: string | number) {

}
test('isText', 2)// error
test('isText', "hey")// works

Destructured rest parameters
Finally, you could use a destructured rest parameter of a discriminated union of tuple types, which behaves like overloads from the caller's side, but can do narrowing in the implementation, unlike overloads:
function test(
    ...[firstParam, secondParameter]:
        ["isText", string] |
        ["isNumber", number]
) {
    //...
}

test('isText', 2)// error
test('isText', "hey")// works

Playground link to code
